# Under the hood of entity group - How to implement it on Cassandra?

Tags: google-app-engine, cassandra

I'm currently working to implement a datastore connector for App Engine to use Cassandra.

I'm thinking about how to implement *Ancestor Paths*. I would like to use in Cassandra an **Ordered Partitioners** and construct my keys like `parent/{key_name or id}` With that I can use **KeyRange** from the API of Cassandra http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#KeyRange.

Do you think it's a good idea? because on datastax we can read using Ordered Partitioners is not really recommended http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/cluster_architecture/partitioning.

I'm really curious to know if Google does that like that because I think entities are ordered by keys.

Answer (score 0):

HBase is much closer to Google's Bigtable than Cassandra is. Cassandra only uses the data model from Bigtable, and Dynamo's distribution model. If one of your primary operations is to scan over key ranges you should not go with Cassandra.

If you must use Cassandra, one way of scanning over key ranges is to use columns to create hierarchy. Basically you create a row for the lowest level, then map the rest of the hierarchy to column names. "parent" would be the row key and the "key_name or id" part would be the column keys. With that model you can scan over a key range by loading a column slice.

Whether or not this is a good idea depends a lot on how your data model looks, I'm not familiar with ancestor paths in GAE, but if you have lots of "parent" things you will get a good balance across the cluster, but if you have few, and lots "key_name or id" it will be inefficient.

Comment: The problem is not to chose this or that database but just how to implement each feature from the API of GAE to Cassandra the better as possible.

Comment: Why do you have to use Cassandra? Shouldn't you start with evaluating which tool to use? I've amended my answer with a suggestion.